# Bazel internal shell issue using windows

Tags: bazel

I am trying to migrate a huge project having visual studio and maven projects to bazel. I need to access our in house maven server which is encrypted. To get access I need the load the maven_jar skylark extension since the default impl does not support encryption (get error 401). using the extension leads to a lot of troubles, like:

```
ERROR: BUILD:4:1: no such package '@org_bouncycastle_bcpkix_jdk15on//jar': Traceback (most recent call last):
        File ".../external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/maven_rules.bzl", line 280
                _maven_artifact_impl(ctx, "jar", _maven_jar_build_file_te...)
        File ".../external/bazel_tools/tools/build_defs/repo/maven_rules.bzl", line 248, in _maven_artifact_impl
                fail(("%s: Failed to create dirs in e...))
org_bouncycastle_bcpkix_jdk15on: Failed to create dirs in execution root.
```

The main issue seems to be the shell that needs to be provided to bazel in BAZEL_SH environment variables:

- I am working under windows
- I am using bazel 0.23.2
- bazel seems to run a bash command using "bash" directly and not the one provided by env variable.
- I got a ubuntu shell installed in windows. bazel was using everything from ubuntu, especially when using maven (settings.xml was using from ubuntu ~/.m2 and not from windows user)
- after uninstalling ubuntu and making sure that bash in a cmd ends up in "command not found" I also removed the BAZEL_SH env var and bazel throws the message above
- after setting the BAZEL_SH variable again it fails with the same error message

I am assuming that bazel gets a bash from somewhere or is ignoring the env variable. My questions are:
1. How to setup a correct shell? 
2. Is BAZEL_SH needed when using current version?

For me the doc at bazel website about setup is outdated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/) to manage your Maven dependencies. It supports both Windows and private repositories using HTTP Basic Authentication.

> For me the doc at bazel website about setup is outdated.

The Bazel team is aware of this and will be updating our docs shortly.